# Apply "Eclipse Workspace Patch" using command line

Tags: eclipse, cvs, patch

For our project we use cvs and we want share changes using patch created using eclipse with configuration in image:
[image]

The patch is like this:

```
### Eclipse Workspace Patch 1.0
#P project2
Index: testFile2.txt
===================================================================
RCS file: testFile2.txt
diff -N testFile2.txt
--- /dev/null   1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
+++ testFile2.txt   1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+
+xxxxxx
#P project1
Index: testFile1.txt
===================================================================
RCS file: testFile1.txt
diff -N testFile1.txt
--- /dev/null   1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
+++ testFile1.txt   1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+
+yyyyyy
```

Is there a command/library allows to apply this patch without eclipse?
I try 'patch' command but seems doesn't supports this patch format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has no simple solution because the format of Multi-project is not standard and only eclipse know how to apply that format.
Standard patch format doesn't know command:

```
#P project1
```

My workaround is:

- generate one patch for single project with name of project follow by '.patch' (Example projectName=project1; patchName=project1.patch);
- genarate patch using format show in follow image

[image]

- apply patch using ant task (wrapping patch command)

  ```
   <target name="applyPatch">
   <echo message="Apply patch:${patchFileName}"/>
   <echo message="workspace.home:${workspace.home}"/>
   <sequential>
       <local name="projectName" />
       <basename  property="projectName" file="${patchFileName}" suffix=".patch" />
       <echo message="${projectName}"/>

       <exec executable="patch">
           <arg value="-d"/>
           <arg value="${workspace.home}/${projectName}"/>
           <arg value="-i"/>
           <arg value="${patchFileName}"/>
           <arg value="-p" />
           <arg value="0" />
           <arg value="-u" />
           <arg value="-N" />
       </exec>
   </sequential>
   </target>
  ```